# Enable location services via ADB or shell

Tags: adb, settings, shell, location-services

I have a rooted phone. Is it possible to enable location services (GPS or network location) via ADB or Terminal Emulator?

Answer (score 20):

On Android 6.0,

To enable:

- GPS: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps`
- Network: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network`

To disable:

- GPS: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps`
- Network : `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network`

On Android 11.0,

To enable:

- GPS: `adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3`

To disable:

- GPS: `adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there anyway we can enable/disable gps and network with one  line adb command. I need it for high accuracy locaton. gps+network =high accuracy

Answer (score 7):

Android location service comes with different options:

1. High accuracy: `gps, network`

   - Enable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps,network`
   - Disable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps,network`
2. Phone only: `gps`

   - Enable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps`
   - Disable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps`
3. Battery saving: `network`

   - Enable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network`
   - Disable: `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network`

Answer (score 5):

`location_providers_allowed` no longer works for Android 10 (API level 29).

Instead, you can set the [`location_mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_MODE) to `LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY` with a value of 3:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3
```

---

**NOTE:** Probably won't work >v29 as this is *already* deprecated as the docs on Location Mode mention:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 28.
>   The preferred methods for checking location mode and listening for changes are via `LocationManager#isLocationEnabled()` and `LocationManager#MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`.

Don't know what a programmatic way to do this through the shell will be once this constant disappears.

Answer (score 4):

- Enable: `adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3`
- Disable: `adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0`

See [Stack Overflow - How to enable/disable GPS location services on Android 9 via ADB commands (not rooted device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559166/how-to-enable-disable-gps-location-services-on-android-9-via-adb-commands-not-r).

Comment: Functions on Android 11.

Comment: @user598527, hi! Thanks for the comment. Currently I don't know.