# Toggle location services via adb in Android 5

Tags: adb, geolocation

I see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/is-it-possible-to-enable-location-services-via-shell) answer from 2013, but now there are options for High Accuracy, Battery Saving, and Device Only.  Also, there was no command for disabling location.

Comment: Regarding the question you linked to in the post. I'm not sure about disabling location services but I would imagine that you could just leave both `gps` and `network` out of the command. As for the various location modes, I would imagine `gps` would represent `Device Only`, `network` would be `Battery Saving` and `gps` and `network` would be `High Accuracy`.

Comment: Should my comment be an answer? The thing is it's kind of me working stuff out. I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: @LJD200 You were close, good guess! I can make my answer on this page a Wiki, if you happen to have any issue with it. :) Just ping me.

Comment: @Firelord No issues at all. This is a fantastic answer. Just out of interest, what would happen if you ran the command with a combination that isn't listed such as `gps` and `wifi` but without `network`?

Comment: @LJD200 Glad you liked it, and good query for the `gps,wifi` -- it will simply activate "device only", the reason is mentioned in my original answer. Google's location service primarily needs `network` as a parameter to activate, so if it is not passed then "high accuracy" and "battery saving" would be out of the question. // And passing only `wifi` would not activate any option on its own.

Answer (score 5):

You may check-out my updated [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114033/96277) dealing with the question in entirety, or consider the following info:

- High accuracy: `gps,wifi,network` or `gps,network` (if you don't want Wi-Fi enabled)
- Battery saving: `wifi,network` or `network` only
- Device only: `gps`

E.g:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps,wifi,network
```

#### To disable Location mode

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed ' '
```

Comment: This used to work on Android 5, but it doesn't anymore on Android 6. With or without root the setting does not change and stays the same as is configured on the system. It probably has something to do with `location_providers_allowed` being deprecated (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED).

Comment: @gw0 My phone has not received Android M update yet, so I am afraid I can't offer any help at the moment.