# Any way to remotely turn on location services without root

Tags: gps-tracking, location-services

so I lost my phone this morning and I tried to use the standard android device manager to track it but it's useless without location services, which I turn off due to it draining too much battery power.

Is there any way to turn it on so I can used ADM or is there another method which can track my phone without location services, maybe using something like wifi hotspots?

I'm not sure which exact android firmware I have but it's above 5.0.0 if that's of any help and it's a xperia z1

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no hope to activate location service remotely without root access or without a system app. Change in the state of location service requires [editing secure settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) which cannot be done without root access or without system UI (user consent) or without a system app having the permission [*android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS). Since your Android doesn't meet any criteria I suggest you do not invest your time anymore in this direction.

As for any other method: I do not know but a local law enforcement agency may be able to assist you with common [mobile tracking techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking).

Related: [Is it possible to enable Location Services via Shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40147/96277)