# Is there a way to enable Google Location Accuracy via ADB or via some other command on Android 13?

Tags: adb, google, location-services

Within location services on Android 13 devices, there are several services such as Google Location Accuracy.

[image: settings page]

I have taken a snapshot of secure, global and system settings before and after enabling this setting, but there is no change, which leads me to believe that we can't change it via settings.

I have tried the solutions mentioned here
[Enable location services via ADB or shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/enable-location-services-via-adb-or-shell)

But these just seem to affect the location setting and not Google Location Accuracy.

Is there a way from ADB to enable/disable this?